# Why does Timespan.TryParseExact not parsing input as expected?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code:

```
var test = TimeSpan.MinValue;
var t = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(
    "03:01 PM", 
    "hh:mm tt", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out test);
```

`t` is showing as false. I'm sure I am missing something, I just can't figure it out!

Comment: Try it without the TryParseExact (just do ParseExact instead) and see what the exception looks like?

Comment: What does `tt` mean in your format string? And can you link the source?

Comment: Hi Adam - I received the following error: "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Use `DateTime.ParseExact`, it has a `TimeOfDay` property. Apart from that(without AM/M) you need to escape the colon with `\\` in `TimeSpan.ParseExact`, so: `"hh\\:mm"`.

Comment: Time span measures an amount of time. So AM/PM has no meaning, and is not supported in the input or the format string.

Comment: Hatchet - that really sucks, I have two text fields the user inputs, one chooses the date, the other chooses the time. I'm trying to take these two text fields and create one datetime field based off them. If I can't properly parse the time due to the lack of am/pm - how could I go about doing this?

Comment: How about `txtDate.Text + " " + txtTime.Text` and parse that?

Comment: hatchet - you should add your response as an answer so I can mark it correct as you were the first to point it out sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time span measures an amount of time. So AM/PM has no meaning, and is not supported in the input or the format string.

This MSDN page details the valid custom format specifiers:
[Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As @Austin Salonen suggested in his comment, since you are trying to obtain a date and time, you should parse your input as DateTime instead of TimeSpan.

Answer (score 3):

It's the AM/PM designator in your string. It shoudn't be there.

`TimeSpan` represents a duration.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to DateTime and it'll work, timespan is for duration, not parsing of dates

```
var test = DateTime.MinValue;
var t = DateTime.TryParseExact("03:01 PM", "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out test);
```